# How to convert table format to string programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

Good day all,

would like request to how to convert table format to string

eg:

```
Material Control     August
Development         September
Planning            August
HR                  September
```

to

**Septembe**r: Development, HR
**August** : Material Control, Planning

```
            List<String> returnvalueStringMonth = new List<String>();
            List<String> returnvalueStringDept = new List<String>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dsSeries.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                string newmanout = dr["MonthNames"].ToString();
                returnvalueStringMonth.Add(newmanout);

                string Departs = dr["Depart"].ToString();
                returnvalueStringMonth.Add(Departs);
                //var DDLName = dr["Depart"];
                //Label dynamicLabel = new Label();
                //dynamicLabel.Text = DDLName.ToString() + ",";
                //div1.Controls.Add(dynamicLabel);
                //var sumPlus = Convert.ToDouble(newmanout) +",";

            }

            List<string> b = new List<string>();
            b.AddRange(returnvalueStringMonth.Distinct());
            for (int cs = 0; cs < b.Count; cs++)
            {
                //Panel aspPanel = new Panel();
                Label dynamicLabel = new Label();
                dynamicLabel.Text = b[cs].ToString()+":" + "<br/>";
                div1.Controls.Add(dynamicLabel);
            }
```

I able achive until month only, then i realize made mistake.
So, please advise how to achive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will fill a list of strings with your desired output. You can change the second loop to do what you want.

```
    var monthList = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dsSeries.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        var key = dr["MonthName"].ToString();
        var value = dr["Department"].ToString();
        if (!monthList.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            monthList.Add(key, new List<string>());
        }

        monthList[key].Add(value);
    }

    List<string> b = new List<String>();
    foreach (var month in monthList.Keys)
    {
        b.Add(month + ": " + String.Join(", ", monthList[month])");
    }
```

If you would rather use LINQ, you can do this instead:

```
var q = from row in dsSeries.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
        group row by row["Month"] into qGrouped
        orderby qGrouped.Key
        select String.Format("{0}: {1}", qGrouped.Key, 
                String.Join(", ", Array.ConvertAll(qGrouped.ToArray(), r => r["Department"])));

var b = q.ToList();
```

Comment: It working fine ..can you explain on 
new Dictionary<String, List<String>>()

Comment: The dictionary here stores lists of strings (the departments for a given month) where the key is a string (the month), so as you go through the rows in the table, you check to see if there is a list in the dictionary for the month in the row. If there is, then you add the department for the row to the list for the month. If not, then you add a list to the dictionary for the newly encountered month in the row, and add the department for the row to this new list. Finally, you join the departments by month in the 2nd loop.

Comment: You're welcome. FYI, I just added a LINQ alternative, if you would rather use that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public string S1 { get; set; }
        public string S2 { get; set; }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        //            Material Control     August
        //Development         September
        //Planning            August
        //HR                  September

        var list = new List<TestClass>
        {
            new TestClass {S1 = "Material Control", S2 = "August"},
            new TestClass {S1 = "Development", S2 = "September"},
            new TestClass {S1 = "Planning", S2 = "August"},
            new TestClass {S1 = "HR", S2 = "September"}
        };

        var listGroupByMonth = list.GroupBy(l => l.S2);
        foreach (var lstByMonth in listGroupByMonth)
        {
            var key = lstByMonth.Key;
            var finalValue = string.Join(", ", lstByMonth.ToList().Select(lbm => lbm.S1));
    }
}
```